# changing from chr to datetime using posixct after using strptime

Tags: r, dataframe, time, posixct

I am attempting to change a few data frames that have columns with date time information that are currently in character format. For instance

```r
$ Date <chr> "5/2/2016 23:59", "5/3/2016 23:59", "4/13/2016 1:08", "4/21/2016 23:59"
```

This is what I have done.

```
weightLog_data[['Date']] <- format(strptime(weightLog_data[['Date']], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M %p")
```

This successfully converts to Y/m/d regular time with am/pm HOWEVER it is still in character format.
$ Date            "2016/05/02 11:59 PM", "2016/05/03 11:59 PM", "2016/04/13 01:08 AM"
I then try to use this function.

```
weightLog_data[['Date']] <- as.POSIXct(weightLog_data[['Date']], format="%Y/%m/%d %I:%M %p")
```

HOWEVER, I receive

```r
$ Date <dttm> 2016-05-02 23:59:00, 2016-05-03 23:59:00, 2016-04-13 01:08:00, 2016-04-21 23:59:00
```

so now am/pm is missing and it is back to military. How do I fix to be  and not be in military format and include am/pm?

Comment: I already explained this to you in a previous question. `POSIXct` just displays that way. If you change the format to get it to print in a certain way, it won't be POSIXct any more. If you want to work in date times in R, you work with POSIXct. When it comes time to print, display, or plot your data, you can convert it back to character. You can't have your cake and eat it, as they say.

Comment: So you are saying posix ct will always display in this format <2016-05-02 23:59:00> missing am/pm and in military time, regardless that I included %p and %I in the code @AllanCameron

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. If you want it to display it in a different way but still have the freedom to manipulate as it if it was POSIXct, you would need to write a new S3 class with its own methods. This isn't hugely difficult, but as I have said before, you don't _need_ it to display differently until you come to present the data somewhere, and that's the point where you format it back into a character vector. If it is really important to you, let me know and I can show you how to write an S3 class, but honestly, this is how people work with date-times in R.

Answer (score 1):

POSIXct just displays that way. If you change the format to get it to print in a certain way, it won't be POSIXct any more. If you want to work in date times in R, you work with POSIXct. When it comes time to print, display, or plot your data, you can convert it back to character. You can't have your cake and eat it, as they say.

Or at least, not without a little effort. It is possible to create your own S3 class that inherits from POSIXct so you can still manipulate it like a POSIXct object. A very rough draft of such a class might be something like this:

```r
as_datetime <- function(x) {
  x <- as.POSIXct(strptime(x, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
  structure(as.numeric(x), class = c("datetime", "POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
            tz = attr(x, 'tz'))
}

as.POSIXct.datetime <- function(x, ...) {
  class(x) <-  c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")
  x
}

format.datetime <- function(x, ...) format(as.POSIXct(x), "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M %p")
```

Now you can feed your data in as character format:

```r
d <- c("5/2/2016 23:59", "5/3/2016 23:59", "4/13/2016 1:08", "4/21/2016 23:59")

as_datetime(d)
#> [1] "2016/05/02 11:59 PM" "2016/05/03 11:59 PM" "2016/04/13 01:08 AM"
#> [4] "2016/04/21 11:59 PM"

data.frame(date = as_datetime(d))
#>                  date
#> 1 2016/05/02 11:59 PM
#> 2 2016/05/03 11:59 PM
#> 3 2016/04/13 01:08 AM
#> 4 2016/04/21 11:59 PM
```

However, there will be a lot of snags and gotchas with trying to use this class. You would need to include an `Ops` method to prevent reversion to POSIXct when manipulating it, and some functions might check class attributes and refuse to run with your new class. Again, there are work arounds for all of this, but IMHO you should just get used to using POSIXct, then when you wish to display the data to someone else, format it however you please *as the final step*.

Comment: Okay, I see thank you! so posixct is simply for working with the data then you can convert it back to character come time for the final results (print, graph, display. thanks!

Comment: Side question: so originally I was only using posix.ct and not strptime for example sleep_data[["SleepDay"]] <- as.POSIXct(sleep_data[["SleepDay"]],format="%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S %p"). This worked. So what is the point in adding strptime function is it only to add the "format=" option and change around the order %y/%m/%d %H:%M?